# Washer drain hoses don't fit our washer

Tags: leak, drain, washing-machine, hose, washer

We have a GE Harmony washing machine. Recently the drain hose sprung a leak at the base. No issues with the connection to the machine, its strictly the hose. We bought both generic hose attachments from Lowes. One is too big, one is too small. There are no other options at our Lowes to try. I looked up our model and make on online to find one to buy, but its a different connection than what we have for a hose at the base. The model online shows it connecting into the machine while ours fits over a hard plastic part sticking out of the washer.

Model: PTWN8050ZM0WW https://www.geapplianceparts.com/store/parts/assembly/PTWN8050M0WW?ModelType=ModelType
Hose suggested: https://www.geapplianceparts.com/store/parts/spec/WH41X10096 Does not fit.

Comment: Your best bet is to contact GE service.

Comment: We finally figured it out. The problem came from the amount of water pressure. The city had recently changed something upstream in the system and someone came by to tell us. Once they did they alerted us they'd be correcting it and now alls right again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

City messed with our pressure. :|

Comment: You can vote for/checkmark your own answer to close this out cleanly